# construct_runtime_integrity_test failing

Tags: runtime, weight, testing

After bumping my substrate branch to 0.9.31 along some other changes,
I came across a test case failure which I have a hard time getting to the bottom of.
The node compiles and runs just fine after adjusting to the newest changes.
However the test case error is as follows:

```
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/node_runtime-663c74491703509f)

running 3 tests
test __pallet_staking_reward_curve_test_module::reward_curve_piece_count ... ok
test __construct_runtime_integrity_test::runtime_integrity_tests ... FAILED
test __pallet_staking_reward_curve_test_module::reward_curve_precision ... ok

failures:

---- __construct_runtime_integrity_test::runtime_integrity_tests stdout ----
thread '__construct_runtime_integrity_test::runtime_integrity_tests' panicked at 'Sensible defaults are tested to be valid; qed: ValidationErrors { has_errors: true, errors: ["[DispatchClass::Normal] Weight { ref_time: 1500000000000, proof_size: 0 } (total) has to be greater than Weight { ref_time: 5346284000, proof_size: 0 } (base block) & Weight { ref_time: 86298000, proof_size: 0 } (base extrinsic)", "[DispatchClass::Normal] Some(Weight { ref_time: 1299913702000, proof_size: 0 }) (max_extrinsic) must not be 0. Check base cost and average initialization cost.", "[DispatchClass::Normal] Weight { ref_time: 2000000000000, proof_size: 0 } (max block) must fit at least one extrinsic Weight { ref_time: 5432582000, proof_size: 0 } (base weight)", "[DispatchClass::Operational] Weight { ref_time: 2000000000000, proof_size: 0 } (total) has to be greater than Weight { ref_time: 5346284000, proof_size: 0 } (base block) & Weight { ref_time: 86298000, proof_size: 0 } (base extrinsic)", "[DispatchClass::Operational] Some(Weight { ref_time: 1799913702000, proof_size: 0 }) (max_extrinsic) must not be 0. Check base cost and average initialization cost.", "[DispatchClass::Operational] Weight { ref_time: 500000000000, proof_size: 0 } (reserved) has to be greater than Weight { ref_time: 86298000, proof_size: 0 } (base extrinsic) if set", "[DispatchClass::Operational] Weight { ref_time: 2000000000000, proof_size: 0 } (max block) must fit at least one extrinsic Weight { ref_time: 5432582000, proof_size: 0 } (base weight)", "[DispatchClass::Mandatory] Weight { ref_time: 2000000000000, proof_size: 0 } (max block) must fit at least one extrinsic Weight { ref_time: 5432582000, proof_size: 0 } (base weight)"] }', /home/magewe/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/399ab89/frame/system/src/limits.rs:335:14
stack backtrace:
   0:     0x55e8e8237b9d - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::libunwind::trace::h9135f25bc195152c
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:93:5
   1:     0x55e8e8237b9d - std::backtrace_rs::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized::h015ee85be510df51
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/../../backtrace/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66:5
   2:     0x55e8e8237b9d - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print_fmt::h5fad03caa9652a2c
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:66:5
   3:     0x55e8e8237b9d - <std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::DisplayBacktrace as core::fmt::Display>::fmt::h2b42ca28d244e5c7
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:45:22
   4:     0x55e8e825b26c - core::fmt::write::h401e827d053130ed
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/fmt/mod.rs:1198:17
   5:     0x55e8e82344b1 - std::io::Write::write_fmt::h1da442c9e1df41d6
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1672:15
   6:     0x55e8e8239665 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::h180c4c706ee1d3fb
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:48:5
   7:     0x55e8e8239665 - std::sys_common::backtrace::print::hd0c35d18765761c9
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:35:9
   8:     0x55e8e8239665 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::h1f023310983bc730
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panicking.rs:295:22
   9:     0x55e8e8239304 - std::panicking::default_hook::h188fec3334afd5be
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panicking.rs:311:9
  10:     0x55e8e8239bf6 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hf26e9d4f97b40096
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panicking.rs:698:17
  11:     0x55e8e8239ae7 - std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}::hfab912107608087a
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panicking.rs:588:13
  12:     0x55e8e8238094 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::h434b685ce8d9965b
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:138:18
  13:     0x55e8e8239819 - rust_begin_unwind
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
  14:     0x55e8e7f44783 - core::panicking::panic_fmt::ha6dc7f2ab2479463
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/panicking.rs:142:14
  15:     0x55e8e7f44873 - core::result::unwrap_failed::h42ad8e915aa0a906
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/result.rs:1814:5
  16:     0x55e8e7fed325 - core::result::Result<T,E>::expect::h508fdebde2aaf018
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/result.rs:1064:23
  17:     0x55e8e7fec4a4 - frame_system::limits::BlockWeights::with_sensible_defaults::h2cffca24e7eea67c
                               at /home/magewe/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/399ab89/frame/system/src/limits.rs:325:3
  18:     0x55e8e7f9b57b - node_runtime::BlockWeights::get::h02bef90c7721618d
                               at /home/magewe/rust/gensyn/node/chain_node/runtime/src/lib.rs:120:57
  19:     0x55e8e7f7684a - <node_runtime::BlockWeights as sp_core::Get<_I>>::get::h777a43037976e2d1
                               at /home/magewe/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/399ab89/frame/support/src/lib.rs:352:14
  20:     0x55e8e7f4d8e4 - <frame_system::pallet::Pallet<T> as frame_support::traits::hooks::Hooks<<T as frame_system::pallet::Config>::BlockNumber>>::integrity_test::hdd296d2b547ea053
                               at /home/magewe/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/399ab89/frame/system/src/lib.rs:367:4
  21:     0x55e8e7f4d7e6 - <frame_system::pallet::Pallet<T> as frame_support::traits::hooks::IntegrityTest>::integrity_test::hf93211ba02b17b2f
                               at /home/magewe/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/399ab89/frame/system/src/lib.rs:364:12
  22:     0x55e8e7f4d936 - <(TupleElement0,TupleElement1,TupleElement2,TupleElement3,TupleElement4,TupleElement5,TupleElement6,TupleElement7,TupleElement8,TupleElement9,TupleElement10,TupleElement11,TupleElement12,TupleElement13,TupleElement14,TupleElement15,TupleElement16) as frame_support::traits::hooks::IntegrityTest>::integrity_test::h3b73eb8016b71165
                               at /home/magewe/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/399ab89/frame/support/src/traits/hooks.rs:219:74
  23:     0x55e8e7f96be6 - node_runtime::__construct_runtime_integrity_test::runtime_integrity_tests::he4135feb2e1f8c75
                               at /home/magewe/rust/gensyn/node/chain_node/runtime/src/lib.rs:544:1
  24:     0x55e8e7f8beaa - node_runtime::__construct_runtime_integrity_test::runtime_integrity_tests::{{closure}}::h05b265d6f91bae10
                               at /home/magewe/rust/gensyn/node/chain_node/runtime/src/lib.rs:544:1
  25:     0x55e8e7f9955e - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h1ef3cb1884ef51ed
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
  26:     0x55e8e7fe5f13 - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h2da14387562cd1a6
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
  27:     0x55e8e7fe5f13 - test::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h307c198d88e9e51a
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/test/src/lib.rs:572:5
  28:     0x55e8e7fe4d1a - <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once::h42564b04a6d1df41
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1935:9
  29:     0x55e8e7fe4d1a - <core::panic::unwind_safe::AssertUnwindSafe<F> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<()>>::call_once::h286b0e8427b9af31
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/panic/unwind_safe.rs:271:9
  30:     0x55e8e7fe4d1a - std::panicking::try::do_call::h0b094c8aa8626e3b
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panicking.rs:492:40
  31:     0x55e8e7fe4d1a - std::panicking::try::h253dd43de0385d2d
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panicking.rs:456:19
  32:     0x55e8e7fe4d1a - std::panic::catch_unwind::h8a89f69958871bf1
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
  33:     0x55e8e7fe4d1a - test::run_test_in_process::h79875496f9bc15c6
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/test/src/lib.rs:595:18
  34:     0x55e8e7fe4d1a - test::run_test::run_test_inner::{{closure}}::hf979093fbdf02646
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/test/src/lib.rs:489:39
  35:     0x55e8e7fb0f4d - test::run_test::run_test_inner::{{closure}}::he01c2dd4903b57d1
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/test/src/lib.rs:516:37
  36:     0x55e8e7fb0f4d - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::hece2f1c514466a0a
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:122:18
  37:     0x55e8e7fb68b8 - std::thread::Builder::spawn_unchecked_::{{closure}}::{{closure}}::h658be5979f99b3a5
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/thread/mod.rs:505:17
  38:     0x55e8e7fb68b8 - <core::panic::unwind_safe::AssertUnwindSafe<F> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<()>>::call_once::h9dbd94372ee944af
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/panic/unwind_safe.rs:271:9
  39:     0x55e8e7fb68b8 - std::panicking::try::do_call::hff71896f3757c3b2
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panicking.rs:492:40
  40:     0x55e8e7fb68b8 - std::panicking::try::hbb4c2c2616b6a189
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panicking.rs:456:19
  41:     0x55e8e7fb68b8 - std::panic::catch_unwind::h72f47810ab7e379e
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/panic.rs:137:14
  42:     0x55e8e7fb68b8 - std::thread::Builder::spawn_unchecked_::{{closure}}::h6331fb85a785812c
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/thread/mod.rs:504:30
  43:     0x55e8e7fb68b8 - core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}::h467656fda03180e5
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
  44:     0x55e8e823e483 - <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once::h56d5fc072706762b
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1935:9
  45:     0x55e8e823e483 - <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<Args>>::call_once::h41deef8e33b824bb
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:1935:9
  46:     0x55e8e823e483 - std::sys::unix::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::ha6436304a1170bba
                               at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library/std/src/sys/unix/thread.rs:108:17
  47:     0x7f90e95268fd - <unknown>
  48:     0x7f90e95a8a60 - <unknown>
  49:                0x0 - <unknown>


failures:
    __construct_runtime_integrity_test::runtime_integrity_tests
```

From this I infer that the error originates from inside the construct_runtime! macro, specifically when generating the BlockWeights inside parameter_types!, which I do in the standard way as such:

```
pub BlockWeights: frame_system::limits::BlockWeights = frame_system::limits::BlockWeights
        ::with_sensible_defaults(WEIGHT_PER_SECOND.saturating_mul(2), NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO);
```

I'm not sure where to look next for the source of this error.
Any hint or suggestion is appreciated!

Kind regards,
Mathis

Comment: Where did you get that code snipe for defining the `BlockWeights` from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question!
The reason for this is the [recent introduction](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12277) of a new component in the Weight struct; the `proof size`.
This makes it mandatory to slightly adjust your definition of `BlockWeights` to account for this:

This expression

```rust
WEIGHT_PER_SECOND.saturating_mul(2)
```

now needs to also needs to declare a maximum proof size:

```rust
WEIGHT_PER_SECOND.saturating_mul(2).set_proof_size(MAX_POV_SIZE)
```

The concrete PoV size limit depends on your chain. Similar to how the maximum normal block weight needs to be defined in the runtime config.

Since Calls currently do not expose pre-dispatch PoV size info; you can set this to `u64::MAX`. However this should be changed once the benchmarking produces PoV weights.

PS: It is better to use `Weight::from_parts` instead of `set_proof_size` since that will cause a compilation error on the next breaking change and you will notice it earlier.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! It indeed resolved the issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer indeed, but this is really annoying since we have no PoV in our chain for instance. What value should I pick and why should I even think about it if it is not applicable 

Comment: You have no PoV or no PoV weight? You have a solo-chain? `u64::MAX` just signals that proof size will effectively be un-limited. For para-chains this will work now, but needs to be adapted in the future. For solo chains its their own responsibility.