# failed to execute TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade: Runtime panicked (Update to 0.9.31 version)

Tags: weight, try-runtime

Once we updated to version 0.9.31 and run try-runtime feature

```
cargo run --release --features=try-runtime,mangata-rococo try-runtime --chain=public-testnet --execution=Native on-runtime-upgrade live --uri wss://roccoco-testnet-collator-01.mangatafinance.cloud:443
```

we receive errors regarding weights
[image]

Can you someone point me where maybe is the problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the same issue as over here [construct_runtime_integrity_test failing](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5557/construct-runtime-integrity-test-failing).
You need to set some Proof size into your block limits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Oliver :) I will try to adjust our code.