# Substrate Error after updating from polkadot version polkadot 0.9.30 to polkadot 0.9.42

Tags: wasm

I have a running chain which was on `polkadot-v0.9.30` and updated all the libraries on to `polkadot-v0.9.42`

No error found while uploading but got error after updating

```
 panicked at 'Sensible defaults are tested to be valid; qed: <wasm:stripped>'
```

The error originates from

```
/// Create a sensible default weights system given only expected maximal block weight and the
    /// ratio that `Normal` extrinsics should occupy.
    ///
    /// Assumptions:
    ///  - Average block initialization is assumed to be `10%`.
    ///  - `Operational` transactions have reserved allowance (`1.0 - normal_ratio`)
    pub fn with_sensible_defaults(expected_block_weight: Weight, normal_ratio: Perbill) -> Self {
        let normal_weight = normal_ratio * expected_block_weight;
        Self::builder()
            .for_class(DispatchClass::Normal, |weights| {
                weights.max_total = normal_weight.into();
            })
            .for_class(DispatchClass::Operational, |weights| {
                weights.max_total = expected_block_weight.into();
                weights.reserved = (expected_block_weight - normal_weight).into();
            })
            .avg_block_initialization(Perbill::from_percent(10))
            .build()
            .expect("Sensible defaults are tested to be valid; qed")
```

```
2023-06-12 12:21:36 panicked at 'Sensible defaults are tested to be valid; qed: <wasm:stripped>', /dep/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/569aae5/frame/system/src/limits.rs:325:9
2023-06-12 12:21:36 Proposing failed: Import failed: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:

    0: 0xfa66b - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x2df7 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h6d1629d4208ae76c
    2: 0x3198 - <unknown>!core::result::unwrap_failed::h8ef12658cee03bf1
    3: 0xe0dc - <unknown>!frame_system::limits::BlockWeights::with_sensible_defaults::hddec9606e207be2d
    4: 0x70937 - <unknown>!<pallet_scheduler::pallet::Pallet<T> as frame_support::traits::hooks::OnInitialize<<T as frame_system::pallet::Config>::BlockNumber>>::on_initialize::h4b32587c5fd765a6
    5: 0x91420 - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::initialize_block::hffb3eafa82bbd60b
    6: 0xa66d5 - <unknown>!Core_initialize_block
```

How to fix this issue ? or is there any guidance around this ?

[image: Screemshot]

Changes made for version updates

- sp_consensus_grandpa and sc_consensus_grandpa
- removed `#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]` since its no longer supporting
- Added #[pallet::call_index()]
- Changed `fn create_verifiable_credential() -> Weight { Weight::from_ref_time(10_000_000_u64)` to `fn revoke_did_document() -> Weight { Weight::from_parts(10_000_000_u64, 1600) }`
- In runtime/build.rs changed to

```
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
   {
       substrate_wasm_builder::WasmBuilder::new()
           .with_current_project()
           .export_heap_base()
           .import_memory()
           .build();
   }
```

Those were the some of significant changes

Did not crash the process, update went smoothly , the error message keeps popping up and blocks are not finalising

This question totally unrelated with [construct_runtime_integrity_test failing](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5557/construct-runtime-integrity-test-failing). since this does not occur in tests and happens after successful runtime update

Comment: The code you link to is not the culprit in this case it is only the bearer of the bad news. Explain and examine the changes you did from 0.9.30 to 0.9.42. Are all weights updated?

Comment: So updated all the weights as per new weights

Comment: @Simson updated

Comment: Are you running your chain locally or are you doing a runtime upgrade?

Comment: I did a runtime update for my locally running chain and this happened @Simson

Comment: Did it reject your update and crash or did it upgrade and then die? (asking all these questions just to make it a better question so just edit and update)

Comment: Did not reject update, 
Not died, not crashed , this error message popping up on terminal

Comment: The question looks good now, I suggested an edit to remove part of the code in the question, which I think is a distraction, and not the root cause.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [construct\_runtime\_integrity\_test failing](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5557/construct-runtime-integrity-test-failing)

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi completely different issues , this did not happen when running tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging  in to version differences I found that I was missing the configuration

```
pub BlockWeights: frame_system::limits::BlockWeights =
        frame_system::limits::BlockWeights::with_sensible_defaults(
            Weight::from_parts(2u64 * WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND, u64::MAX),
            NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO,
        );
```

This causes the whole execution to panic after.

So Make sure you have updated all the runtime configuration for the version 0.9.42

```
parameter_types! {
    pub const BlockHashCount: BlockNumber = 2400;
    pub const Version: RuntimeVersion = VERSION;
    /// We allow for 2 seconds of compute with a 6 second average block time.
    pub BlockWeights: frame_system::limits::BlockWeights =
        frame_system::limits::BlockWeights::with_sensible_defaults(
            Weight::from_parts(2u64 * WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND, u64::MAX),
            NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO,
        );
    pub BlockLength: frame_system::limits::BlockLength = frame_system::limits::BlockLength
        ::max_with_normal_ratio(5 * 1024 * 1024, NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO);
    pub const SS58Prefix: u8 = 42;
}
```

Comment: Did you run the runtime integrity test? It should have caught that panic.

Comment: I did run all the tests